# java: file read, modify outside, then read again, modification not seen

Tags: java

I have set of files which will be served by a servlet based on a parameter. The servlet opens stream to required file, reads, writes to http response and closes the stream. Now this file can be modified manually and saved. Then next time a request comes for this file, servlet opens a stream to this file, writes it to the response, but I see the content is not the modified one, its the old one.

If I restart tomcat, servlet responds with modified content. Can it be made to read the modified content without restart?

Its not tomcat caching, the string read from file reader itself is unchanged.

thanks!

Here's the content of the servlet-

```
InputStream fhandle=this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("responses/"+file);

        if(fhandle!=null){
            Reader fr=new InputStreamReader(fhandle);
            PrintWriter out=resp.getWriter();
            int a=-1;
            FileWriter fos=new FileWriter("copyFile.xml"); //to compare what's read with actual file
            while((a=fr.read())>=0){
                fos.write(a);
                out.write(a);
            }
            out.flush();
            fos.close();
            fr.close();
            fr=null;
            fhandle.close();
            fhandle=null;
            System.gc();
        }
        else
            System.out.println(file+" not found");
```

After hitting the servlet for first time, I will edit the file and save it. Now again I will hit the same servlet for the same file, and I will not get the edited content.

Comment: Can you give more code about file modification? A normal problem for this kind of bug could be you forget to close the file stream after modifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources are not reloaded dynamically when the associated files change. Resources are part of the source tree, distributed with the application. They aren't expected to change. There is something seriously wrong with your design if you require this behaviour.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Here do you mean to say, the file once read is not read again, the content comes from somewhere?

Comment: @Murali I don't know what else 'not reloaded dynamically' could possibly mean.

Comment: Reloaded to where? work directory is not where it loads the file, cause I have tried after removing it and still the content is same.

Comment: @Murali The content will always be the same until you redeply the application. I repeat there is something seriously wrong with your design if you expect otherwise.

Comment: I was creating a mock webservice that would serve static response for app development. I wanted to change the response and be able to see that served without need to restart the server. Tomcat context xml config "reloadable=true" solved the issue. thanks anyway.